# Custom Marker Interface in Java

Tags: java, serialization, polymorphism, cloneable, marker-interfaces

As Serializable and Cloneable is marker Interface (interface which is not having any method), so if we create our own marker interface then what will be the difference between these two.

Comment: Was my answer acceptable or do you need other clarifications?

Answer (score 0):

`Serializable` and `Cloneable` are standard interfaces. They both belongs to "protected" packages (which means you cannot add classes to them - well you can, but it's not something you do everyday).

```
java.io.Serializable
java.lang.Cloneable
```

They're recognized by the JVM at runtime.
For example calling `clone()` on an object which does not implement `Cloneable` will throw a

```
java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException
```

You might want to use marker interfaces for **custom** runtime checks, or even for *compile time processing*. However the recommended way is to use *annotations*.

Comment: what you have written is right but if we create our custom marker interface. they will also recognise by JVM at runtime and even if we  bound the program that if its containing the instance of our custom marker interface then do this work. Then what will be the difference in both....

Comment: @SumitSingh mmh I think I'm missing your point. Could you maybe write an example of what you'd like to do?